# Active directory login using Apache shiro

Tags: ldap, shiro

We have a Java based application, where we are using **CN** as login.
However we want to use **samAccountName** as userId.
Following is the shiro.ini

```
contextFactory=com.trmsys.cargo.shield.shiro.ldap.JndiExtLdapContextFactory
contextFactory.url=ldaps://ldaps.test.net:636
contextFactory.systemAuthenticationMechanism=simple
contextFactory.systemUsername=CN=SRV,OU=ServiceUsers,DC=test,DC=net
contextFactory.systemPassword=12WEty%^
contextFactory.environment[java.naming.security.protocol]=ssl

ldapRealm=com.trmsys.cargo.shield.shiro.ldap.JndiLdapRoleRealm
ldapRealm.contextFactory=$contextFactory
ldapRealm.userDnTemplate=CN={0},OU=AppUsers,DC=test,DC=net
ldapRealm.searchBase=OU=Groups,DC=test,DC=net
ldapRealm.searchUserBase=OU=AppUsers,DC=test,DC=net

ldapRealm.groupObjectClass=group
ldapRealm.uniqueMemberAttribute=member
ldapRealm.uniqueMemberAttributeValueTemplate=CN=0},OU=AppUsersDC=test,DC=net
```

Can anybody please provide the proper way of making the desired change.

Comment: It looks like you have a custom realm: `com.trmsys.cargo.shield.shiro.ldap.JndiLdapRoleRealm` does this extend one of the Shiro LDAP realms?

Comment: @Brian: Yes it is.

Comment: which one? what does your implementation change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the correct way of doing this.
We have to make changes in the following line

```
ldapRealm.userDnTemplate=CN={0},OU=AppUsers,DC=test,DC=net
```

Changes would be like following

```
ldapRealm.userDnTemplate={0}
```

Now, **sAmAccountName** can be used as userId. While logging in, username should be used as either "domain/account" or "account@domain".

If we do not want to use "domain/account", change as following

```
ldapRealm.userDnTemplate=domain/{0}
```

Now user id would be "account". [account == value of sAmAccountName]